# Rendering Elements from Object Array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, babeljs

I am trying to render the objects inside of an array using React. What I am trying to achieve is to create a menu which takes the nested Object as an input and return the objects. However, the return function on line 62 is not returning the **const renderedItems**

```
const renderedItems
```

which is supposed to render everything. Please let me know when am I going working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div id='root' class='container'></div>


<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/babel">
    const starter = [{
            "Item": "Warm spiced olives & prosciutto ",
            "Price": "6",
            "DescriptionPrimary": "Description One",
            "DescriptionSecondary": "Description Two"
        },
        {
            "Item": "Crusty sourdough bread (2pc)",
            "Price": "9",
            "DescriptionPrimary": "with a choice of garlic butter or olive oil and balsamic vinegar",
            "DescriptionSecondary": "Description Two"
        },
        {
            "Item": "Tasmanian oysters 6 or 12",
            "Price": "12",
            "DescriptionPrimary": "Natural $20.90/$39",
            "DescriptionSecondary": "Kilpatrick(GF/DF) $24/$42"
        },
        {
            "Item": "Rainbow trout patÃ© (GF available)",
            "Price": "15",
            "DescriptionPrimary": "served with crusty sourdough",
            "DescriptionSecondary": "Description Two"
        }
    ];

    function MenuItem(props) {
        return (
            <div className="menu-item">
                <div className="item-title">
                    <div>{props.item}</div>
                    <div>{props.itemPrice}</div>    
                </div> 
                <div className="item-description">
                    <div>{props.itemDescriptionOne}</div>
                    <div>{props.itemDescriptionTwo}</div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        );
    }

    function ReturnMenu(props) {
        const numbers = props.numbers;
        const renderedItems = numbers.map((number) => {
            <MenuItem item={number.Item} itemPrice={number.Price} itemDescriptionOne={number.DescriptionPrimary} itemDescriptionTwo={number.DescriptionSecondary}/>
            console.warn("This was done")
        });
        
        // console.log(renderedItems.Item);

        return (
            <ul>{renderedItems}</ul>
        );
        // return "Task completed sucessfully!";
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
        <ReturnMenu numbers={starter} />,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
</script>
```

Comment: Well, I answered first. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
 const renderedItems = numbers.map((number) => {
            <MenuItem item={number.Item} itemPrice={number.Price} itemDescriptionOne={number.DescriptionPrimary} itemDescriptionTwo={number.DescriptionSecondary}/>
            console.warn("This was done")
        });
```

You need to either return:

```
const renderedItems = numbers.map((number) => {
            return <MenuItem item={number.Item} itemPrice={number.Price} itemDescriptionOne={number.DescriptionPrimary} itemDescriptionTwo={number.DescriptionSecondary}/>
            console.warn("This was done")
        });
```

... or (my preferred option) remove the braces:

```
const renderedItems = numbers.map((number) => <MenuItem item={number.Item} itemPrice={number.Price} itemDescriptionOne={number.DescriptionPrimary} itemDescriptionTwo={number.DescriptionSecondary}/>);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look here, you forgot to `return` the value. Add a `return` before `<MenuItem` and put the `console` before it.:

```
const renderedItems = numbers.map((number) => {
  console.warn("This was done");
  return <MenuItem item={number.Item} itemPrice={number.Price} itemDescriptionOne={number.DescriptionPrimary} itemDescriptionTwo={number.DescriptionSecondary}/>;
});
```